# How to determine optimal value for pg_stat_ramdisk_size on Amazon RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Amazon [announced](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.RamDisk) they support a RAM disk for the `stats_temp_directory` in PostgreSQL on RDS.

This sounds like a good idea so I want to enable it. Now I'm wondering how to determine the optimal size for the RAM disk. Is there a way to show the current size of the directory on disk? The file system of PostgreSQL on RDS is not accessible, isn't it?
Also, what happens if the RAM disk is configured too small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`pg_stat_ramdisk_size`](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1700/) controls the location and size of the `stats_temp_directory` on RAM. It's easy to determine the size on bare metal or *out of the RDS* by issuing a `du -h`  over the directory specified on the variable. There is no way yet to access this folder size at RDS.

The used space on this folder, will depend strictly on the settings you have for `track_*` variables (See [27.2.1. Statistics Collection Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) ). It is not necessarily a huge amount of space, although is very write intensive as it holds the counters per global and database basis (counters over database per table/index/functions). This also means it is more related to the number of databases and tables+indexes (as `pgstat_write_statsfiles` at postmaster/pgstat.c iterates, writing the PgStat_StatDBEntry) than the amount of data.

You don't want to have it smaller (as a crash will happen), so you may want to start with a value over 256MB.

Per configuration, it won't let you set `pg_stat_ramdisk_size` higher than 8 GB (accepts values from `1` - `8196` and the unit is `MB`).

> PGSTAT_FILE_FORMAT_ID 1 byte
> PgStat_StatTabEntry  = 164 bytes
> PgStat_StatFuncEntry = 28 bytes
> closingChar = 'E'
> describers is a char (T or F in this case)

As will be explained later, not all the tables, indexes, and functions are written on the *db statsfile*. A basic formula is *SizeOfDBStatFile = PGSTAT_FILE_FORMAT_ID + describers + (tableCount * PgStat_StatTabEntry) + (funcCount * PgStat_StatFuncEntry) + closingChar*.

A `select count(*) * 164 "size in bytes" from pg_class where relkind IN ('r','i','S')` will give you the estimate for the tables if all of them were flushed on the file. Also, you need to do the same within `pg_proc`, but instead the factor will be 28 bytes.

This file is *one per database*.

> PgStat_StatDBEntry = 180 bytes
> PgStat_GlobalStats = 92 bytes
> PgStat_ArchiverStats = 114 bytes
> describer is a char (D)

The global statfile is smaller and contains only the global stats and the counters across databases. Should be something close to *PGSTAT_FILE_FORMAT_ID +describer + PgStat_GlobalStats + PgStat_ArchiverStats + (PgStat_StatDBEntry + describer) * numDatabases*.

As you can see, the limitation imposed by AWS in regarding is way above the amount of data held on this directory in most of the databases that can run inside RDS expectations.

[My blog post reference](http://web.archive.org/web/20190801000000*/http://www.3manuek.com/pgstatramdisksize)

Comment: I forgot to mention that not all the functions have an allocation on this file. Only users functions.